# The Filter condition using multiple XPATH fails

Tags: xpath, filter

I am trying to implement multiple filter using the `xpath` such that the output of the filter is all the `CompoundEmployee` nodes which have the following:

- All the `job_information` first occurrence should not have `employee_class` as `EX`
- All the `job_information` first occurrence can have all the `events` than `26`
- The `event` `26` can appear only in the case when `last_modified_on` = `custom_date1`

The source `xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse> 
        <CompoundEmployee> 
            <person> 
                <employment_information> 
                    <job_information> 
                        <employee_class>WC</employee_class> 
                        <event>26</event> 
                        <event_reason>FUNDBREA</event_reason> 
                        <last_modified_on>20170215</last_modified_on> 
                        <custom_date1>20170215</custom_date1> 
                    </job_information> 
                </employment_information> 
            </person> 
       </CompoundEmployee> 
  </queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

The xpath filter I am using is

```
/queryCompoundEmployeeResponse/CompoundEmployee[person/emplo‌​yment_information/jo‌​b_information[1]/emp‌​loyee_class!='EX' and (person/employment_information/job_information[1]/event='26' and person/employment_information/job_information[1]/last_modifi‌​ed_on=person/employm‌​ent_information/job_‌​information[1]/custo‌​m_date1) ]
```

I am getting an error during runtime.

Can you help me in this.

Thanks,
Vicky

Comment: Please consider pasting your code as text https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I tried but was getting error during the post

Comment: The XPATH I am using /queryCompoundEmployeeResponse/CompoundEmployee[person/employment_information/job_information[1]/employee_class!='EX' and (person/employment_information/job_information[1]/event='26' and person/employment_information/job_information[1]/last_modified_on=person/employment_information/job_information[1]/custom_date1) ]

Comment: XML -<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
   <CompoundEmployee>
      <person>
         <employment_information>
            <job_information>
               <employee_class>WC</employee_class>
               <event>26</event>
               <event_reason>FUNDBREA</event_reason>
               <last_modified_on>20170215</last_modified_on>
               <custom_date1>20170215</custom_date1>
            </job_information>
         </employment_information>
      </person>
   </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below and let me know the result:

```
//CompoundEmployee[person[employment_information[job_information[not(employee_class="EX")][not(event="26") or last_modified_on=custom_date1]]]]
```

Above expression should return

`CompoundEmployee` node

- that includes `person`

  - that includes `employment_information`

    - that includes `job_information`

      - with `employee_class!=EX`
      - and `event!=26`
      - but if `last_modified_on==custom_date1`, then `event==26` is also acceptable